# How to pass a HWND to my graphics class to create a graphics device

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, directx, parameter-passing

Ok. So I'm trying to make a small framework to work with graphics before I move to VS 2012.
I can already make the window appear and I've even created a graphics class, but when I try to pass a HWND from the window to my graphics class I get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SZJerkXXI's Framework, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  MWindow.cpp
1>DXGraphics.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Direct3DCreate9@4 referenced in function "public: __thiscall DXGraphics::DXGraphics(struct HWND__ *)" ( 0DXGraphics@@QAE@PAUHWND__@@@Z)
1>C:\Users\jader\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SZJerkXXI's     Framework\Debug\SZJerkXXI's Framework.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

After registering, creating and displaying a window with the HWND "hWnd".
The next thing I do is create an object to my class:

```
DXGraphics Game(hWnd)
```

Since my construcor looks like

```
DXGraphics::DXGraphics(HWND hWnd)
{
pDirect3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION );

D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
ZeroMemory( &d3dpp,sizeof( d3dpp ) );
d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE;
d3dpp.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;

pDirect3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                         D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                         hWnd, /*  <-- handle to the window I can't pass... */
                         D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING | D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE,
                         &d3dpp,
                         &pDevice );
}
```

I'm following some tutorials and looking things I don't understand in MSDN but I'm stuck here. I don't know why won't It pass the HWND. I even downloaded the code from the tutorial and it does the same thing but it works there.

PS:
I'm using DirectX and I've already included the directories and libraries.
And I've been coding for a few months but I want to progress so that's why I want to know what I did wrong. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: That has nothing to do with passing the handle. You need to link to the Direct3D library. The documentation for `Direct3DCreate9` points it out at the bottom.

Comment: Ok it seems the directx sdk didn't install correctly due to a conflict with my version of visual studio. But now the problem is that after i uninstalled vs 2010, correctly installed the sdk and reinstalled visual studio the compiler can't find the header files for iostream, string, cstdlib and others i've been using. It seems that it defaulted to the directx header files since it can still use those. How ccan i fix or reset this?

Comment: @JaderJRivera When you removed VS2010 did you remove the runtimes aswell? (ie: remove software -> visual studio runtime etc)

Comment: @FlorisVellleman. Well I'm not too sure. All I did was enter the Control Panel and uninstall all of the redistrutable visual studios, since I don't know why I had the versions 2005, 2008 & 2010. I also removed somthing name the QLServer (or something around that line). Then when I reinstalled visual srudio it promted me if I wanted to install the QLServer 2008, since I didn't think it was important I denied.

Comment: This is not due to the window handle, this is an link error, you need to link to d3d9.lib in order to use function Direct3DCreate9